# How to add MapIcon when clicked on MapControl in UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, bing-maps

I have a mapcontrol element (XAML):

```
<Custom:MapControl 
           Name="MyMap"  
           Style="Terrain"                          
           ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"  
           TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"    
           MapServiceToken="My key2" ZoomLevel="12"/>
```

And I am placing a MapIcon on the map with known latitude and longitude numbers:

```
public void InitMap()
        {
            // Get position
            Geopoint Home = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 50, Longitude = 3 });
            // Create POI
            MapIcon myPOI_Home = new MapIcon { Location = Home, NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0, 1.0), Title = "", ZIndex = 0 };
            myPOI_Home.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Home.png"));
            // Add to map and center it
            MyMap.MapElements.Add(myPOI_Home);
            MyMap.Center = Home;
            MyMap.ZoomLevel = 16;
            MyMap.LandmarksVisible = false;

        }
```

I would like this to happen when you click on the map. So wherever you click on the map it will place the icon at those coordinates.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [maps tapped event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.maptapped?view=winrt-20348).

Something like:

```
MyMap.MapTapped += (object sender, MapInputEventArgs args) => {
    var loc = args.Location;

    //Add code to add your pin.
};
```